# What are the reasons for cellForRowAtIndexPath getting called more than once for every row

Tags: ios, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I have a tableview and I have 20 prototype cells and tableview's **Content** parameter is **Dynamic Prototypes**

At a time I show only one protoype cell but for some weird reason **cellForRowAtIndexPath** is getting **called twice**.

I have gone through my code and I call **reloaddata** just once.

I couldn't figure out what could have caused tableview to call **cellForRowAtIndexPath** twice !

so i generally would like to know what and all could cause tableview to call **cellForRowAtIndexPath** more than once for the same row

### Update:

In one of the prototype cells if a button is clicked then probably I would reload the data so that I can show some other prototype cell but then also its called twice

but still number of rows count is one

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Without seeing your code it is impossible to say.

Comment: The code is so big ! Let me update you in a while

Comment: Can I encourage you to break out all your `UITableViewController` code into a separate project. Test it there in isolation, and verify it there if you're able.

Comment: @DanRam any luck finding the cause?

Comment: The code is bit confidential to share .. hope you understand my concern

Comment: @DanRam I can understand that.. but I already explained and showed on an example that the `UITableView` does not call those method twice unless explicitly asked.. therefore I believe that in your case the problem lies somewhere in rest of your code. and without seeing it, we cannot help you find it.

Answer (score 3):

If you call `reloadData()` explicitly yourself, that would explain it. The `tableView` loads data by default in `UITableViewController`, so explicitly calling it again would trigger `cellForRowAt` the second time. You can easily confirm this by removing an explicit call to `reloadData()` - then the `tableView` should look correctly and the `cellForRowAt` should be called only once.

I tested a following minimal working example in Playgrounds, and it got called only once:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class A: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Reload", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(buttonPressed))
    }


    @objc func buttonPressed() {
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print(">>>> calling numberOfRowsInSection")
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        print(">>>> \(indexPath)")
        return UITableViewCell()
    }

}

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = UINavigationController(rootViewController: A())
```

So unless you do something else, the `cellForRowAt` should be called really just once per `reloadData()`.

Comment: @DanRam do following: `print(">> Begin")` then `tableView.reloadData()` and then `print(">> End")`... in the `cellForRowAt` add this line: `print(">>>> \(indexPath)")`.. then show me the output that gets printed

Comment: @DanRam any news brother?

Comment: As you said I am using tableviewcontroller but calling reloaddata on first time. in viewdidload .. causes the **cellForRowAtIndexPath** to be called twice and it makes sense because its tableviewcontroler and so it'd call by itself once and if we call explicity then it will make the tableview load again that makes sense but ... when a button is clicked and I am loading the table manually with reloaddata so that I can load some other cell but this time cellforRowIndexpath should not be called twice but it's called twice I don't understand this ...

Comment: @DanRam follow my previous comment and let me know what happend

Comment: its printed like ">>Begin" and then ">>End" then 0 then again 0

Comment: Number of rows in section called twice and cellForRowAtIndexPath as well when I call reload data in view did load but when I call reload data on button click then Number of rows in section is getting called once and cellForRowAtIndexPath  is getting called twice.. some times on button click event Number of rows in section called once and cellForRowAtIndexPath  called once not twice .. its confusing to me

Answer (score 0):

By default there is a call when view controller is initialized to reload the tableView when you add another one then it's 2

Comment: one on view didload and others on button fire events of tableviewcells

Comment: you use delegate in cell button action or how you call reload from cell button ???

Comment: I have used addTarget